# Civi Case DB Error: no such table

Tags: civicase

Any help please?
Issue with Case dashboard and case tab on contact summary. No of this makes any sense to me???? civi 5.13.4

I have deleted all files and SQL database and restored from previous backups - same issues

civibackTrace

```
#0 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->_constuct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#3 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#4 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", "1146 ** Table 'brpcvshome_cvs.civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming' doesn't exist")
#7 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#9 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#10 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#11 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(439): DB_DataObject->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#12 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1491): CRM_Core_DAO->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", TRUE)
#13 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php(639): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#14 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(87): CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(NULL, (Array:0), "dashboard", TRUE)
#15 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(116): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->preProcess()
#16 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->run((Array:2), NULL)
#17 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#18 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#19 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#20 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#21 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/c...")
#22 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/components/c...")
#23 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#24 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() 
#25 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#26 /home/brpcvshome/domains/thecvs.org.uk/public_html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#27 {main}
```

Comment: Try disabling and enabling CiviCase component.

Comment: Also make sure the mysql database user has the create views privilege.

Comment: Thanks everyone...very much appreciated! Disable and enable works as you suggested...

Answer (score 1):

The stackbot bumped this so I figured I'd post an answer.

If you are on less than 5.37, as per the comments you can disable then re-enable CiviCase and it will recreate the views.

If you are on 5.37 or higher, the views no longer exist and this won't come up. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19642.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can see one file name there that I do not think is part of core CiviCRM? This is the table `brpcvshome_cvs.civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming`.

That is potentially a table that is part of an extension or some local customization. Is your CiviCRM database actually called brpcvshome_cvs? If not, it might well be that you missed restoring a separate database? And if it is, can you check if that table is actually there?

Comment: Hi ErikH it is part of civicase - it's a view that gets created when you enable civicase, hence Pradeep's suggestion.

Comment: Ah it is a view, forgot to check that, only looked at the tables :-( My bad!